# Hide a table row with filtering jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/MxqRu/1/

When you click on 2010 I need valuation to disappear with the list items.

Here is the code which I am using to do this:

```
$("#yearfilter a").live("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //var v = $(this).val();
                var v = $(this).attr("data-value");
                if(v.length > 0) {
                    $('tr.reports').show();
                    $('tr.reports ul').hide();
                    $('tr.reports ul.year-'+v).show();
                    $('tr.reports').each(function() {
                        if($('ul:visible', this).size() == 0) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('tr.reports').show();
                    $('tr.reports ul').show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each tr an ID something like `id="row_2010"` then look for that and hide the whole entire row at once.

**UPDATE**

I would strongly suggest not using so many tables and use more classes to classify your data structure. It would help your javascript be much more clean, concise and function easier.

**UPDATE**

I adjusted all your javacsript and some of your html. Here is a fully working example [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brenjt/fSnYq/1/)

Comment: the tr is just a container it will have different years - so when no years are shown then the valuation would disappear

Comment: So you are saying that if all the options inside let's way the valuation row are hidden then the entire row needs to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in my project something like this:

```
function toggleRow(row_id) {
    row_selector = "#row_" + row_id;
    $(row_selector).toggleClass("shown hidden")
}
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.hidden {display:none;}
.shown {}
```

Then in the HTML I have alternating table rows, where the odd rows act as headings for the content in the even rows. Clicking an odd row toggles the visibility of the corresponding even row.

```
...
<tr onclick="toggleRow(17)">...</tr>
<tr class="hidden" id="row_17">...</tr>
...
```